# proof of Zassenhaus formula for exponentials of linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

The Zassenhaus formula is

$$e^{t(X+Y)}= e^{tX}~  e^{tY} ~e^{-\frac{t^2}{2} [X,Y]} ~
e^{\frac{t^3}{6}(2[Y,[X,Y]]+ [X,[X,Y]] )} ~
e^{\frac{-t^4}{24}([[[X,Y],X],X] + 3[[[X,Y],X],Y] + 3[[[X,Y],Y],Y]) } \cdots$$

from [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#The_Zassenhaus_formula).

$X$ and $Y$ are linear operators, and $[X,Y]$ is their commutator.

I mostly want to prove it for the case where the commutator of $X$ and $Y$ is a constant, or simply the general proof.

What I'm looking for is either a reference to a place where it's proven or at
least some shove in the right direction.

So far I've tried to just expand the exponential to see if I see anything
but have no ideas so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the case $[X,Y]=c$ ($c$ a constant) is sufficient for you:
notice that
$$\frac{d}{dt}e^{tX}e^{tY}e^{-t^2c/2}=Xe^{tX}e^{tY}e^{-t^2c/2}+e^{tX}Ye^{tY}e^{-t^2c/2}
-tc\,e^{tX}e^{tY}e^{-t^2c/2} =(*).$$
As $e^{tX}Ye^{-tX}=Y+ct$ (to see it: the derivative of both sides is $c$ and the value for $t=0$ is $Y$), we have
$$(*)=(X+Y)e^{tX}e^{tY}e^{-t^2c/2}.$$
If $F(t)=e^{tX}e^{tY}e^{-t^2c/2}$, we have $F(0)=1$ and $dF/dt=(X+Y)F(t)$, which are the defining relations for $e^{tX+tY}$.

Comment: thank you I understand it, do you have any idea of a place here the full proof is shown? Do you know how this topic of mathematics is called, cause I got to it from quantum mechanics and I'm not sure what the name of the branch is

Comment: How is there a asymmetry in the original formula? The fourth factor as 2 in front of $[Y,[X,Y]]$, but 1 infront of $[X,[X,Y]]$. If I swap X and Y shoudn't the formula remain the same, as $X+Y=Y+X$

Comment: @ramanujan_dirac: surely $X+Y=Y+X$, but $e^{tX}e^{tY}\neq e^{tY}e^{tX}$

Comment: oops, sorry. My mistake.