# Flow of sum of non-commuting vector fields

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Let $V,W\in\Gamma(M)$ be any two vector fields. Is there any "nice" expression for the flow of $V+W$ in terms of the flow of $V$ and the flow of $W$? It would be sufficient for me to have some sort of expansion in $\epsilon$ for the flow of $V+\epsilon W$, at least the first few terms (or even just at the order of $\epsilon$).

In the case where $[V,W]=0$, it is pretty easy to show that
$$\varphi_{V+W}^t = \varphi_V^t\circ\varphi_W^t,$$
but the non commuting case is of greater interest to me.

Comment: In the paper "A Lie Group Structure on the Space of Time-Dependent Vector Fields" (A. Poscilicano) you can find an explicitly formula for the flow you're looking for. I won't explain now because I still don't understand it thoughourly,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the general non-commuting case, the flow $\phi^t_{V+W}$ equals to first order both $\phi^t_V \circ \phi^t_W$ and  $\phi^t_W \circ \phi^t_V$. Morally, the second order approximation should be 'halfway between' the two aforementioned flows. Since $\phi^{t}_V \circ \phi^{t}_W \circ \phi^{-t}_V \circ \phi^{-t}_W$ is approximated by $\phi^{t^2}_{[V,W]}$, we expect to have

$$ \phi^t_{V+W}(x)= \left(\phi^{t^2}_{\frac{1}{2}[V,W]} \circ \phi^t_W \circ \phi^t_V\right)(x) \, .$$

It happens to be the first few terms of the [Zassenhaus formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#The_Zassenhaus_formula) (in reverse order) for the exponential map ; Notice that we can interpret a vector field on a manifold $M$ as an element of the Lie algebra of the infinite dimensional Lie group $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$, so that taking the exponential map $\mathfrak{diff}(M) \to \mathrm{Diff}(M)$ corresponds to integrating vector fields.

Comment: Would you happen to have a reference for those facts?

Comment: No, I don't have any particular reference for these particular results. If you want to work with the flows directly, any differential geometry book should give you ideas on how to proceed. For instance, I got ideas from Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifold* and Arnold's *Mathematical Methods in Classical Mechanics*. It appears that flows behave a lot like exponentials, a phenomenon best explained by the last remark in my answer. There are subtleties related to the fact that $\mathfrak{diff}(M)$ and $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$ are infinite dimensional which may cast doubt on the use of the exponential

Comment: The only book I know on these matters is Kriegl and Michor's *The Convenient Setting of Global Analysis*. In any case, for this kind of problem, the exponential map works as usual. If you really are doubtful, notice that $\mathfrak{diff}(M)$ and $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$ embed in the space of linear endomorphisms $C^{\infty}(M, \mathbb{R})$ (use Lie derivative and pullback respectively), so that the exponential map under interest is essentially the one studied in functional analysis. In this case, take a look at this paper by Suzuki : http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103901324

Comment: If you are not so doubful, then the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula shows that exponentials (and hence flows) commute up to strictly higher order terms. Hence, in some approximation, we might as well take the highest order terms to commute with everything else. In this case, up to reversing order, the Zassenhaus formula is proved in this discussion : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165535/proof-of-zassenhaus-formula-for-exponentials-of-linear-operators

Comment: Yes, actually the exponential map and the BCH formula were the main motivations for my question. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be a partial answer based on the contents of the paper

> A Lie Group Structure on the Space of Time-Dependent Vector Fields"
>   (A. Poscilicano)

In that paper the author deals with time dependent vector fields. A usual vector field is a particular case of that so that will work in your case.

If $X$ and $Y$ are time-dependent vector fields on a manifold $M$ the following identity holds $$\Phi^{X+(\Phi_{t, 0}^X)_*(Y_t)}_{t, s}=\Phi^X_{t, 0}\circ \Phi^Y_{t, s}\circ \Phi^X_{0, s}.$$ You're invited to check this. Then, instead of using the vector field $Y$ we are going to apply this to the time dependent vector field $(\Phi_{0, t}^X)_*(Y_t)$. Using that $$(\Phi_{t, 0}^X)_*(\Phi_{0, t}^X)_*(Y_t))= (\Phi_{t, 0}^X\circ \Phi_{0, t}^X)_*(Y_t)=(\Phi^X_{t, t})_*(Y_t)=Y_t,$$ we are lead to $$\Phi^{X+Y}_{t, s}=\Phi^X_{t, 0}\circ \Phi^{(\Phi_{0, t}^X)_*(Y_t)}_{t, s}\circ \Phi^X_{0, s}.$$ Generally, if $X$ is a vector field then we can see it as a time-dependent vector field and the following relation holds $$\Phi^X_{t, s}=\Phi^X_{t-s},$$ where the right hand side is the usual flow of $X$. Use this to apply to your case.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what $(\Phi_{0,1}^X)_{*}(Y_t)$ is?