# Why does $e^{A}e^B=e^{A+B+\frac12[A,B]+...}$ imply $e^{A+B}=e^{A} e^B e^{-\frac12[A,B]+...}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

The Campbell-Baker-Hausdorff formula says the following $$e^A e^B=e^{A+B+\frac{1}{2}[A,B]+\dots}$$

I am reading a text that says the following

> The Campbell-Baker-Hausdorff formula implies that $e^{A+B}=e^A e^B e^{-\frac{1}{2}[A,B]+\dots}$

How does the first formula imply the second? The whole point of this concept is that we can't simply separate $e^{A+B+\frac{1}{2}[A,B]\dots}$ into $e^{A+B}e^{\frac{1}{2}[A,B]+\dots}$

Comment: The [Zassenhaus formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff_formula#The_Zassenhaus_formula) dual to CBH.

Comment: Near [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165535/proof-of-zassenhaus-formula-for-exponentials-of-linear-operators?rq=1).

Answer (score 5):

$e^{A+B} = e^A e^B D$ where $D = e^{-B}e^{-A}e^{A+B}$.  Now by CBH applied to $-A$ and $A+B$,
$$\eqalign{e^{-A} e^{A+B} &= \exp\left(B + \frac{1}{2} [-A,A+B] + \ldots \right)\cr
&= \exp\left(B - \frac{1}{2}[A,B] + \ldots\right)}$$
and then using CBH again with $-B$ and $B - \frac{1}{2}[A,B]+\ldots$,
$$ \eqalign{D = &\exp \left(-\frac{1}{2} [A,B] + \frac{1}{2} [-B, B - \frac{1}{2} [A,B] + \ldots]\right)\cr 
   & = \exp\left( - \frac{1}{2} [A,B] + \ldots\right) } $$
(here anything with a product of three or more $A$'s and $B$'s goes in the $\ldots$).

Comment: Thanks! Also, I think you mean $B-\frac{1}{2}[A,B]$ in the line "...and then using CBH again with $-B$ and $B-[A,B]$..."?

Comment: Yes (edited it).